# How to use PHP to get DateTime from XML node?

Tags: php, xml, datetime

I am trying to use PHP to read an XML file that has a `<date>` node like this:

```
<service>
    <date>2018-10-26T15:38:28-02:00</date>
</service>
```

This date format is not read correctly, but if the format of the date omits the time portion like this:

```
<service>
    <date>2018-10-26</date>
</service>
```

It reads ok. The PHP code I'm using is:

```php
$xml = new XMLReader();
$xml->open('file.xml');

while( $xml->read() ){
    if($xml->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $xml->nodeType != XMLReader::END_ELEMENT && $xml->name == 'service'){
        $inner = new SimpleXMLElement($xml->readOuterXml());
        $date = $inner->date;
    }
}
```

I read some articles here in Stack Overflow explaining that the problem is the colons in the date, and I should use brackets to read it, but the examples were for nodes with colons in the node name, not in the value. I tried using brackets anyway, but no matter what I do it doesn't read.

Does anyone know how can I read it with PHP?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `XMLReader`, any reason you are using that and `SimpleXML`? Seems a bit confusing to use 2 XML parsers. SimpleXML itself doesn't have an issue with `2018-10-26T15:38:28-02:00`, https://3v4l.org/7fLbO.

Comment: You need to use the `DateTime` class's constructor get get a `DateTime` instance: `$date = new \DateTime($inner->date);`